# How to read CSV file with Pandas with timezone aware index properly?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-datetime

I am trying to read a .csv file which has 1048575 rows and 3 columns, there might be some missing indexes.

The .csv file looks like this

[CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Emr75.png)

I wrote this line of code to read the .csv file using Pandas

```
df=pd.read_csv('GHI.csv',thousands=r',',sep=';',usecols=['Time','Value']).
```

The dataframe which is, however, read incorrectly as the length of the dataframe and the tail of it shows me incorrect timestamps.

[DataFrame Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iV7r1.png)

Can someone please let me know how to parse this file properly and make the timestamps timezone aware.

Thanks,
Debayan

Comment: parse the dates using the [parse_dates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#date-handling) argument in read_csv.

Comment: Do you mean adding this to the argument list parse_dates=['Time'],infer_datetime_format=True

Comment: Anyway, I tried with the arguments, still, it is the same.

Comment: I shared a link to the docs, that extensively explains how to go about parsing dates. kindly have a look at it. if infer fails, you can write a custom function, or pass a format for how pandas should read in the dates. but the docs i bliv will guide u much better

Comment: Hi, I tried several combinations but none of them worked. Can you please look into the two screenshots I attached and tell me where I might be going wrong? Also, the line is taking almost 5-6 minutes to execute every time.

Comment: can u share what u tried(data, not pics), let's see what the error is. include ur code as well.

Comment: I tried this: df= pd.read_csv('GHI.csv',thousands=r',',sep=';',usecols=['Time','Value'],parse_dates=['Time'],quotechar='"')                                                                         and also                                                                                                                                     df= pd.read_csv('GHI.csv',thousands=r',',sep=';',usecols=['Time','Value'],parse_dates=['Time'],quotechar='"',date_parser=pd.io.date_converters.parse_date_time)

Comment: not sure what else i can suggest apart from what is in the docs. hopefully someone else can suggest sth to solve the challenge